# how to remove when I am using .includes String prototype

Tags: javascript

In my code we are adding the users using .includes(), I tried searching about this problem on : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype

but I could not find anything useful, in my case I want to  delete the users now, looking for this function, how this could be possible?

```
activate(model) {
  this.model = model;
  this.users = this.model.users.models.map((user) => {
    user.$isSelected = model.addedUsers.includes(user);
    return user;
  });
}

addusers() {
  this.addedUsers = this.users.filter((b) => b.$isSelected);
  this.dialogController.ok(this.addedUsers);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem over here? witch function, what the current result?

Comment: i want delete the users, I am adding with .includes

Comment: Looks like you're using .includes() correctly... but could you clarify what the difficulty is for removing a user?

Comment: hi roger, I just dont know how to do this :9, I tried splice, removes, delete and none works, so I confuse how I could do this, .includes include the user right?, thank you

Comment: No, str1.includes(str2) checks if str2 can be found within str1 and returns true or false. It doesn't add anything to the string.

Comment: I don't see why you'd use a string for this in the first place, unless for some reason you have to. You'd probably have better luck keeping the users in an array

Comment: You got the wrong link. The `includes` you are using is [the array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: `includes()` will return true if the object is in the Array, it won't add anything. If you want to remove it you'll need to use a combination of `indexOf()` and `splice()`